# How to call a function which returns an int in Scala data frame and append it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am having a dataframe like

```
x  y
_  _
1  10
2  30
3  50
4  24
5  36 
6  45
```

I want to append another column z which will be depending on the value of y.

So i created a function

```
def  GiveNumVal(col: Column) => Integer = {

      if(Column>=0 && Column<15){
        return 1;
      }
      else if(Column>=15 && Column<30){
        return 2;
      }
      else if(Column>=30 && Column<45){
        return 3;
      }

     else if (Column>=45 && Column<=59){
        return 4;
      }
      else{
        return 0;
      }
    }
```

And I call by

```
val new_df=df.withColumn("z",GiveNumVal($"y"));
```

It cant even compile. I am not sure where is the wrong part.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're checking `Column`'s value where you should be checking `col`'s value. Apart from that, what you have created is just a Scala function and cannot be used with Dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the `udf` to be used or create a `udf` like this one

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
// create dataframe
val df = Seq(
  (1, 10),
  (2, 30),
  (3, 50),
  (4, 24),
  (5, 36),
  (6, 45)
).toDF("x", "y")

//create udf 
def giveNumVal = udf((c : Int) => {
  if(c >=0 && c <15) 1
  else if(c >=15 && c <30) 2
  else if(c >=30 && c <45) 3
  else if (c >=45 && c <=59) 4
  else 0
})
```

And use it as

```
val new_df=df.withColumn("z",giveNumVal($"y"));
```

If you have a general function and want to use as udf then you can register as

```
//general function 
  def giveNumVal = (c : Int) => {
    //implementation here 
  }

//To register 
  val GiveNumVal = spark.sqlContext.udf.register("functionName", giveNumVal)
```

Output :

```
+---+---+---+
|x  |y  |z  |
+---+---+---+
|1  |10 |1  |
|2  |30 |3  |
|3  |50 |4  |
|4  |24 |2  |
|5  |36 |3  |
|6  |45 |4  |
+---+---+---+
```

**Note:** You don't need `return` statement and `;` in scala

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `when` *inbuilt function* inside your `GiveNumVal` function because **if else condition won't work on columns**.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def  GiveNumVal(col: Column) = {
  when(col >= 0 && col < 15, 1).otherwise(
    when(col >= 15 && col < 30, 2).otherwise(
      when(col >= 30 && col < 45, 3).otherwise(
        when(col >= 45 && col <= 59, 4).otherwise(0)
      )
    )
  )
}
val new_df = df.withColumn("z", GiveNumVal($"y"))
new_df.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---+
|x  |y  |z  |
+---+---+---+
|1  |10 |1  |
|2  |30 |3  |
|3  |50 |4  |
|4  |24 |2  |
|5  |36 |3  |
|6  |45 |4  |
+---+---+---+
```

**`GiveNumVal` function returns a `column` and not an `Integer`**

I hope the answer is helpful